# localStorage error when trying to load content

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function to highlight words:

```js
// This is to read previews highlights when user reload the page
var myContent = localStorage.getItem("text"); // it not highlight the previews texts
          for(var i = 0; i < myContent.rangeCount; i++) {
            highlightRange(myContent.getRangeAt(i));
          }




function myFunction() {
              var userSelection = window.getSelection();
              //localStorage.setItem("text", userSelection); // save to localstorage
              for(var i = 0; i < userSelection.rangeCount; i++) {
                highlightRange(userSelection.getRangeAt(i));
              }
}
    
    
    
    function highlightRange(range){
      span = document.createElement("span");
      span.appendChild(range.extractContents());
      span.setAttribute("style","background:#ffc570;");
      range.insertNode(span);
    }
```

```html
<button type="button" id="myCheck" onClick="myFunction()";>Click to highlight</button>
<br>
<div>Some text to highlight</div>
```

I'd like to save at localstorage all the highlights to show again after user reload the page. The problem is that highlights disappear after I reload the page. What I am doing wrong?

(note that I comment the setItem just to make code snippet work cause localstorage is not allowed in it).

Comment: You can store just strings in localStorage. If you want to store more complex data, first you have to `JSON.stringify` it, then you have to `JSON.parse` when you get it back.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an class that changes the background color to yellow and select that class using a javascript function!

HTML:

```
<div class = "highlight">Some text to highlight</div>
<button onclick = "highlight()">Click to highlight</button>
```

CSS:

```
.text_highlighted{
  background-color: yellow;
  height: fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

JS:

```
function highlight(){ 
    const text = document.querySelector('.highlight');
    text.classList.toggle("text_highlighted");
}
```

You can also check this on codepen: https://codepen.io/HaibaoM/pen/rNpQRMx

I hope it will help!